# Teamviewer 8 on Kubuntu 13.04 won't start

Tags: installation, 13.04, wine, kubuntu, teamviewer

The problem is I can't run Teamviewer on Kubuntu. That problem exists for me since 12.10 and I as I remember, it was with the 7th version either. I download official package from officical web site, for 64 bit system. Install it, then install all dependencies (apt-get install -f). When I start it, window with License agreement appears and I can't agree with it, because I don't see anything, even mouse cursor is invisible on window area. Here's the trace of teamviewer from console:

```
kirokko ~ $ teamviewer 

Init...
Checking setup...
Launching TeamViewer...
fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"MountMgr" failed to start: 2
fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"PlugPlay" failed to start: 2
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity ((nil),-1,(nil),(nil),0,3,(nil),0,(nil)) - stub!
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000100, 00000000): partial stub.
fixme:resource:GetGuiResources (0xffffffff,0): stub
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32dc60,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW (L"\\\\.\\DISPLAY1",0,0x32d918,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),1,0x32dc60,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:winhttp:WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl discovery via DHCP not supported
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter 233 00000001
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter 4a 00000001
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter 407 00000001
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter 49 00000001
fixme:bitmap:CreateBitmapIndirect planes = 0
fixme:bitmap:CreateBitmapIndirect planes = 0
fixme:wtsapi:WTSRegisterSessionNotification Stub 0x1005a 0x00000000
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000122-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80040155
err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {00000122-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}, 80040155
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter c04f 00000001
fixme:richedit:ME_HandleMessage EM_SETFONTSIZE: stub
fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0xffffffff at address 0xf7585c5a (thread 0009), starting debugger...
err:seh:start_debugger Couldn't start debugger ("winedbg --auto 8 5552") (2)
Read the Wine Developers Guide on how to set up winedbg or another debugger
```

What's the problem? The same problem was when I had Ubuntu 12.10 installed, then the same problem was when I installed Mint 14 KDE (Kubuntu 12.10). Now I moved to Kubuntu 13.04 and the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the `ia32-libs` package? I installed team viewer recently on a 12.04 kubuntu box and I had to install that package to make it work.

Comment: I think yes, because it's all installed as dependencies (install -f option using apt-get). I checked that and I got message that everything installed and is up to date.